# Trouble loading modules in a JavaScript web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker, netlify

I've got a web worker `primes.js` that I want to break up into smaller files. Not having any luck.

First thing I did was to load the Worker as type:module:

```
worker.current = new Worker('primes.js', {type: module})
```

Executing this worker works okay.

Next I move some code from `primes.js` to `primeTest.js` and export a function.

```
...
export function primeTest {...}
...
```

I then add an import statement to `primes.js`:

```
import primeTest from './primeTest'
```

However, this results in a MIME error, stating that primeTest is of type 'text/HTML'.

If I change the import statement to

```
import primeTest from './primeTest.js'
```

the MIME error goes away, no console error appears, but the app hangs when the worker is called. I put a debugger statement in the web worker, but it's not triggered.

I'm using Netlify's build/deploy scripts, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used named export:

```
export function primeTest {...}
```

So you have use named import

```
import { primeTest } from './primeTest.js'
```

You can also use default export:

```
export default function primeTest {...}
```

And import default

```
import primeTest from './primeTest.js'
```

Comment: Thank you, that very thought occurred to me as I came to check for an answer.